# sensor_msgs/CompressedImage decompression

Tags: ros, opencv, sensor-msgs, compressedimage, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I cannot use this type of data: sensor_msgs/CompressedImage. I've trasformed the originale image stream with the "image_transport" package, to send image over internet. Now i need to trasform this compressed image in a usable image (a sensor_msgs/Image or somethink like).

Any suggestions??

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51490/sensor_msgs/compressedimage-decompression/) by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-01-04**:
Are you attempting to decompress the raw bytes outside of ROS or simply to subscribe to a compressed image stream using ROS on a remote machine?

**Comment by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on 2013-01-04**:
I need to use image stream in ros. I hope to transform compressImage data in a CvMat :D or any opencv data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED:

With instruction:
cv::Mat matrix = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(buffer_image_compressed),1)

it's possibile to use the compressed image in opencv!

---

Originally posted by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) with karma: 136 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on 2013-01-18**:
what type is buffer_image_compressed? sensor_msgs::CompressedImage?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using ROS check out this answer:
http://answers.ros.org/question/35183/compressed-image-to-image/

You would use this like:

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/internet/image out:=/camera/image
```

Where the topic for your internet stream is:

```
/internet/image/compressed
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2018-05-09**:
Thank you @Chad Rockey . It was quite thoughtful of you to say that the internet stream image topic name. Very Useful!